# Como converter uma coluna do dataframe pyspark em uma lista?

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, dataframe, python-requests, spark

Boa tarde pessoal, eu tenho um dataframe gerado no pyspark e gostaria de transformar esse dataframe em lista, vocês saberiam uma forma de converter?

Eu estou pegando os itens do dataframe e passando para uma lista de linha a linha mas está demorando um pouco. Caso alguém saiba uma outra forma de passar os dados do dataframe para uma lista mais performático seria de grande ajuda.

```
df_nome_funcionario = spark.sql("""
SELECT NM_FUNCIONARIO 
FROM VENDAS.NM_FUNCIONARIO
ORDER BY NM_FUNCIONARIO
GROUP BY NM_FUNCIONARIO
""")

vetor_principal = []

tam_df = df_nome_funcionario.count()

i = 0
while i < tam_df:
    print('Carregando posicao do vetor: ', i)
    vetor_principal.append(df_nome_funcionario.collect()[i][0])
i=i+1
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de passar os elementos do dataframe para uma lista no pyspark, a princípio o dataframe tem só uma coluna.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o mais rápido seria fazer uso dos métodos `.rdd` e `.flatMap`, pois estes se utilizarão dos recursos do Spark.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_nome_funcionario.select(col("COLUNA")).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Answer (score -1):

Gerando um exemplo de df:

```
df_nome_funcionario = spark.createDataFrame([('Romário',), ('Ronaldo',), ('Bebeto',)], ('NM_FUNCIONARIO',))
df_nome_funcionario.show()

+--------------+
|NM_FUNCIONARIO|
+--------------+
|       Romário|
|       Ronaldo|
|        Bebeto|
+--------------+
```

Usando collect_list para gerar a lista:

```
df.agg(collect_list(col("NM_FUNCIONARIO"))).collect()[0][0]
```

output:

```
['Romário', 'Ronaldo', 'Bebeto']
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Para converter uma coluna em um dataframe pyspark em lista, basta você utilizar o método **toPandas()** na coluna que você quer converter em lista, dessa forma:

Exemplo:

```
df_nome_funcionario = spark.sql("""
SELECT NM_FUNCIONARIO 
FROM VENDAS.NM_FUNCIONARIO
ORDER BY NM_FUNCIONARIO
GROUP BY NM_FUNCIONARIO
""")

df_nome_funcionario.show()

# Saída: Exemplo de saída criado pelo Luiz Viola
#
# +--------------+
# |NM_FUNCIONARIO|
# +--------------+
# |       Romário|
# |       Ronaldo|
# |        Bebeto|
# +--------------+
```

Aplicando o método toPandas()

```
returnValue = list(df_nome_funcionario.select('NM_FUNCIONARIO').toPandas()['NM_FUNCIONARIO'])

# Saída:
# ["Romário", "Ronaldo", "Bebeto"]
```

Sei que é contra intuitivo a conversão de um dataframe spark para pandas, só que em testes de benchmarck feitos pela comunidade essa foi a solução mais performática. Por experiência própria utilizando esse método em comparação com o collect() chegou a ser mais de 10x mais rápida.

**Referência do benchmarck dos métodos**:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120999/11700945

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia me informar o problema nessa resposta para que eu possa melhorar?

Answer (score -1):

Uma das alternativas é utilizar list comprehension

`vetor_principal = [item[0] for item in df_nome_funcionario.select('NM_FUNCIONARIO ').collect()`]

Com o item[0] você pega o que está contido dentro da *row*.
O *collect* é o comando que você utiliza para executar uma ação.